# Groovy in Jenkins - spread not yet supported for CPS transformation

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a list of Strings:

```
def parsed_list = ['29/29(100%)', '36/36(10%)', '32/32(100%)', '18/18(100%)', '18/18(100%)', '6/6(100%)']
```

I would like to extract percentage values: 100%, 100%, 100%, 100%, 100%, 100%

I'm trying with these piece of code:

```
def percentages = parsed_list*.find(/\d+%/)
```

But I get this error: `spread not yet supported for CPS transformation`

What should I improve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try without spread operator

```
parsed_list.collect{it.find(/\d+%/)}
```